# xslt/XML eliminate duplicate attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I want to delete duplicate values from the result my XSLT gives so far.

My input (two tags to do my examples, but there are more than 5000 tags to process):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE ficAlimMENESR SYSTEM "ficAlimMENESR.dtd">
<ficAlimMENESR>
<!-- versionAF="AAF-VE1812" -->

<addRequest>
<operationalAttributes><attr name="categoriePersonne"><value>PersEducNat</value></attr></operationalAttributes>
<identifier><id>4</id></identifier>
<attributes>
<attr name="GPEIPersonJointure"><value>4</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIPersonStructRattach"><value>5001</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIPersonFonctions"><value>5001$ENS$ENSEIGNEMENT$P0222$LETTRES ANGLAIS</value><value>4873$ENS$ENSEIGNEMENT$P0222$LETTRES ANGLAIS</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsDiv"><value>5001$5$5 SEGPA</value><value>4873$2CAPT$2nde cap ter</value><value>5001$5$5 SEGPA</value><value>5001$CAP2 APR$CAP2 APR</value><value>5001$CAP2MMEV$CAP2 MMEV</value><value>5001$5$5 SEGPA</value><value>5001$5$5 SEGPA</value><value>5001$CAP2 APR$CAP2 APR</value><value>5001$CAP2MMEV$CAP2 MMEV</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsGpes"><value/></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsMatieres"><value>5001$030201$ANGLAIS LV1</value><value>4873$006600$ACCOMPAGNEMENT PERSONNALISE</value><value>5001$509800$ACCOMPAGN.EDUCATIF- PRATIQUE ORALE LVE</value></attr>
</attributes>
</addRequest>

<addRequest>
<operationalAttributes><attr name="categoriePersonne"><value>PersEducNat</value></attr></operationalAttributes>
<identifier><id>8</id></identifier>
<attributes>
<attr name="GPEIPersonJointure"><value>8</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIPersonStructRattach"><value>6623</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIPersonFonctions"><value>6623$ENS$ENSEIGNEMENT$L0426$ESPAGNOL</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsDiv"><value>6623$1ITEC1$1STI2D-ITEC</value><value>6623$TSIN1$TERM-STI2D-SIN</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsGpes"><value>6623$1ES1_ESP2$</value><value>6623$1ITEC1_ESP2$</value><value>6623$2ESP2-3$</value><value>6623$2ESP2-5$</value><value>6623$TESP2-2$</value><value>6623$TSIN1_ESP2$</value><value>6623$1ACITEC_ESP2$</value><value>6623$1ESP2-2$</value><value>6623$TESP2-1C$</value></attr>
<attr name="GPEIEnsMatieres"><value>6623$030602$ESPAGNOL LV2</value></attr>
</attributes>
</addRequest>

</ficAlimMENESR>
```

i'm using xlst 3.0 and this is my script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="us-ascii"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="addRequest">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes"/><xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attributes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="attr[@name='GPEIEnsDiv']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attr[@name='GPEIEnsDiv']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="value"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">        
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of  select="substring-before($var1,'$')"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the result that i got, so i want to delete duplicate values

```
5001,4873,5001,5001,5001,5001,5001,5001,5001,
6623,6623,
5264,5264,5264,5264,5264,5264,5264,5264,
,
5044,5044,5044,5044,5044,5044,5044,5044,
6621,
,
```

if i understand, i have to rewrite it like this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="us-ascii"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="addRequest">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes"/><xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attributes">
   <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(attr[@name='GPEIEnsDiv']/value/substring-before(.,'$'))" separator=","/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How is input file?

Comment: We need to see the input file so we can tell where the duplicates are coming from.

Comment: I put distinct-values like :
<xsl:apply-templates select="distinct-values(attributes)"/><xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

But this show error ? below the sources

Comment: Using `distinct-values` should help to eliminate duplicates, you will need to be a bit more specific on whether the complete result is not supposed to contain any duplicates or whether you want to eliminate duplicates when outputting the values from each `attributes` element. The code you now have does the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, as you seem to use XSLT 3, you can often simply use `distinct-values` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="attributes">
   <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(attr[@name='GPEIEnsDiv']/value/substring-before(.,'$'))" separator=","/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I try to use this but it is not valid xsl

Comment: That template I posted of course has to be put into a complete stylesheet but it seems you have managed to do that and your attempt does not give any error for me at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5DG/1. So please be more specific as to which error you get and which tool you use that says "it is not valid xsl".

Comment: I try it like that link you show me,
in the link there are not error it's working well,
but i'm using xsl transformation in XML Tools 2.4.9.2 pluging with notepad++ 7 and it show me  error "Unable to apply transformation on current source. Make sure that XSL is valid ", i don't know why ?

Comment: XSLT 3 was finalized as a specification in 2017 and is implemented in some XSLT 3 processors like Saxon 9.9 and Saxon 9.8 and AltovaXML release 2017 and later but it is not magically supported by older software released before. So to use XSLT 2 or 3 you need to use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor, not sure whether Notepad++ allows you to integrate one.

Comment: Tank you for your answers, i'm going to try XML copy editor 1.2 to see if it's working well

Comment: hello, i back, i can't find an open source application using xslt 3.0.
i download Saxon 9.9 but i don't know how to run it.
please can you propose me one ?

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/ on how to run Saxon 9.9, you can get the open-source HE edition on Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.9/. Ask a new specific question with all the details of what you tried and what got wrong if you really can't get it to work.

Comment: I downloaded saxon he, i make test using this "java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -t -qs:"current-date()" it's working well.
I added my xml, dtd and xsl files in the folder SaxonHE9, so when i try this script "java -cp saxon9he.jar test.xml ADO1.xsl " it's show me error like "unable to find or load the main class test.xml"

Comment: To run XSLT from the command line, you either need `java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:test.xml -xsl:ado1.xsl` or `java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:test.xml -xsl:ado1.xsl`. As I said, feel free to ask a new question with all details if you run into trouble, but I don't think it makes sense trying to solve that here within the comments.